# How to add a library's .pc file to a specific directory?

Tags: c++, opencv, pkg-config

How can I add a newly installed library's `.pc` file to `pkg-config`'s path. In my experience this happens automatically, but not with recently installed `opencv3` via `homebrew`.

Most of my libraries' `.pc` files are in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` (including `opencv`), but not `opencv3`

The library `opencv3` exists in `/usr/local/cellar`, and does have a `opencv.pc` in `/usr/local/cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_4/lib/pkgconfig`.

Now I need `pkg-config` to find it, but I think it makes more sense to add this `.pc` to an existing path rather than add a whole new path.

Is there a recommended process to add it? Thank you very kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noted the same. You can just specify a full path to a `.pc` file instead of using a `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

So, I tend to use this in `bash` and double up the dollars in `Makefile` since it avoids having to change anything when I upgrade:

```
pkg-config ... $(find /usr/local/cellar/opencv3 -name "opencv*.pc")
```

My method assumes that I don't keep multiple versions of `hombrew` package version lying around - which I do not anyway - YMMV!