# OS X g++ not finding OpenCV libraries

Tags: c++, opencv, linker-errors

I have OpenCV 3.3.1 installed on OS 10.13.1 using Homebrew, and I'm getting a linker problem I can't diagnose. Does anyone have a clue what might be going on?

Command line:

`` g++ backsub.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -o backsub ``

Returns the following error message:

```
ld: library not found for -llibopencv_stitching.3.3.1.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Using the `-v` option gives, for the linker section (hard wrapped to make it easier to read):

```
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.
xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.
xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64
-macosx_version_min 10.13.0 -o backsub
-L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.3.1_1/lib
/var/folders/zn/p7grv7lj49lfdrvrtn7mp1kh0000gn/T/backsub-2eda30.o
-llibopencv_stitching.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_superres.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_videostab.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_photo.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_aruco.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_bgsegm.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_bioinspired.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_ccalib.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_dpm.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_face.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_fuzzy.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_img_hash.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_line_descriptor.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_optflow.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_reg.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_rgbd.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_saliency.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_stereo.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_structured_light.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_phase_unwrapping.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_surface_matching.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_tracking.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_datasets.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_text.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_dnn.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_plot.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_xfeatures2d.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_shape.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_video.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_ml.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_ximgproc.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_calib3d.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_features2d.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_highgui.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_videoio.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_flann.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_xobjdetect.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_imgcodecs.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_objdetect.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_xphoto.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_imgproc.3.3.1.dylib
-llibopencv_core.3.3.1.dylib -lc++ -lSystem
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.
xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
ld: library not found for -llibopencv_stitching.3.3.1.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

pkg-config seems to be doing the right things. All of the dylibs are in `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.3.1_1/lib` and have the exact filenames specified in the command line. For some reason the linker isn't seeing them. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you need `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv3` maybe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40437596/2836621

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I confirmed the Homebrew 3.3.1 installation of OpenCV installs just one .pc file, at `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.3.1_1/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc`. From the expanded command line above I'm pretty sure pkg-config is doing the right thing, linking to the 3.3.1 libraries and with the correct location. Those libraries are on disk, but for some reason the linker doesn't see them.

Comment: Please post output from `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` and also from `ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.3.1_1/lib`

Comment: Just as a temporary workaround, try using `$(pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv | sed 's/-llibopencv_stitching.3.3.1.dylib//')` instead of your `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv`

Comment: Output from `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv`: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fDJF6FQM), output from `ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.3.1_1/lib`: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/TPre9BL3). When I execute ``g++ backsub.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv | sed 's/-llibopencv_stitching.3.3.1.dylib//'` -o backsub`` it complains no library found for `-llibopencv_superres.3.3.1.dylib`, the next on the list. For some reason the linker can't see any of the dynamic libraries. It's really odd.

Comment: Have you updated Xcode from AppStore and re-done `xcode-select —install` since any upgrades to new version of macOS?

Comment: I updated to Xcode 9.1 a while ago, and command line tools are installed. `xcode-select -p` returns `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

Comment: Clutching at straws here, but have you tried `clang++` and have you tried adding `-std=c++11`?